# Ajax callback function with html class name depend from function position in html

Tags: ajax, function, jsf, primefaces, callback

I would like to pass the idname to the ajax callback function, but without write this name inside the function. Is it possible? Something like a myfunction($(this).parents('allTst'))

```
<div class="allTst" id="idname1">

 <p:commandLink>
  <f:ajax onevent="myfunction('idname1')">
 </p:commandLink>

</div>
<div class="allTst" id="idname2">

 <p:commandLink>
  <f:ajax onevent="myfunction('idname2')">
 </p:commandLink>

</div>
```

Comment: Clarifying: you want to get the `id` property of the closest (relative to `event.target`) parent element that has class `allTst`?

Comment: Hi, you could understand better if you read the answer under the thread. Just I have problem to implement this answer...could you see it?

Comment: If that was what you wanted, then the answer to my question is "yes". I don't know why BalusC removed his answer, it seemed quite fitting. What parts did you have a problem with?

Comment: Hi mabi...the BalusC answer could be correct if I use simple onclick javascript. But with a oncomplete in primefaces, if I put oncomplete='myfunction(this)', the server return something more long inside the p:commandLink -> <a href . So the keyword THIS looks like point to something else and not to the A tag. PF print this: onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_idt6',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){provaritorno(this);}});return false;" So like you can see there is more code and THIS maybe don't look about A tag.

Comment: Maybe the answare is inside XHR,STATUS,ARGS and maybe I could use this, but I don't know how.

Comment: HTML events in general have `this = window`. You can get the element that triggered the event by using `event.target` where `event` is the event object. How do you get that in primefaces, I can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: Hi mabi. Ty...I'm near to the solution with your comment. I used mufunction(event) and not myfunction(this). So in the callback function I wrote function(myvar){$(myvar.target).hide()} Now is near to the perfection. The problem now is that the target DIV inside have more elements. If I click some element inside this div, the HIDE() method go only for what I click, and not for all contenitor object. that's a problem. Looks like if target is not the content of the <p:commandLink> but what I click inside that. Do you have some solution? Ty very much really u r great